# How to Bind textbox/ListBox from one List with depending on other Dropdownlist populated with Another Sharepoint list in InfoPath?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, forms-services

I have a `DropDownList` which is populated with One SharePointList in `INFOPATH DESIGNER` and the value for other textboxes are filled depending on this DropDownList Selected Value using `Rules & Action`. This works fine.

But, now i want to retrieve data in TextBox or ListBox which is present in Other List.`(Want to use ClientID as LookUp value)`depending on the Selected value of Dropdownlist.

Example

```
ClientList(ClientID,Name,City)
ClientAddress(ClientID,Address1,Address2)
```

Depending on `ClientID` from `DropDownList` the `TextBox` Value must be filled with Corresponding `Address1,Address2`

Answer (score 0):

> I have a DropDownList which is populated with One SharePointList in
>   INFOPATH DESIGNER...

Controls (one of which is  Dropdown ListBox) cannot be populated in Infopath Designer. They are populated in Infopath Filler on client machine or in browser on server but in Infopath data forms (or in Infopath web parts in ASPX webpart webpages), infopath XML data forms in case of library forms,  generated on the basis of and linked to published XSN template (for edit/update, display/view, new/create modes). Only templates and only designed in Infopath Designer. One can define data sources (data connections), for example,  to  sharepoint lists for controls in Infopath Designer

> But, now i want to retrieve data in TextBox or ListBox which is
>   present in Other List.(Want to use ClientID as LookUp value)depending
>   on the Selected value of Dropdownlist

This seems like a standard cascading Dropdown Listbox [the descriptions of which are abundant on the internet](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=cascading+dropdown+listbox+infopath)

Comment: Hello @Gennady thanks for reply! but i want to use it with TWO DIFFERENT SHAREPOINT LIST! Plz guide me..!

Comment: Infopath cascading dropdown listboxes use different sharepoint lists. Get any article on it from intenet